# hide the clicked element if returned value is not true (Angular 4)

Tags: angular

**APP Summary:**

I am building an app in which users guess the RGB value, if **guess value** is true then it will change all these elements to **same color**, if guess value is not true then it will **hide** that selected element, and user can guess from the remaining elements.

**Problem:**

I added this in my voter.component.html file, but its not working

```
<a href="#"> <li (click)="compare(i)? style.background-color='rgb({{item}})' :style.display='none'" style.background-color="rgb({{item}})"></li>
```

[Here is my stackblitz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7d3f1h)

Comment: Tried this one also, but not working.. I have added my working code in above link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to pass element handler like this:

> .HTML

```
<a href="#"> 
    <li #elem (click)="compare(i, elem)>
</li>
```

> .ts

```
compare(i: number, element: any){
   if(i === numberToCheck){
       element.style.display = 'none'         
   }
}
```

UPDATED:

your compare function:

```
compare(i, element)
  {
    if(this.list[1]==this.list[i])
    {
      for(let k = 0; k < this.list.length; k++){
        this.list[k] = this.list[i]
      }
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      element.style.display = 'none';
      return false;
    }

  }
```

Comment: if both RGB value matches then, how can i make all the boxes color same?

Comment: Create a loop for your list and for each item assign your RGB color, next overwrite your list variable. angular should refresh your html list with elements that have the same RGB values

Comment: @kappo your `comparison_variable` vas invalid so i replace this with some hardcode (`this.list[1]`). Try my example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qecrwt

Comment: this is my updated code, I have compared the values and when user hit the correct option i want that the remaining boxes should have same color

Comment: change your foreach for this: `this.list.forEach((e, index) => {`

Comment: and `this.list[i] = null;` should look like this : `this.list[i] = '';`

Comment: can u make stackblitz of that

Comment: because i did what you said but color of the remaining boxes is not changing

Comment: I'm glad i could help :)

Comment: what is e in the compare function what is its purpose?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159486/discussion-between-witold-tkaczyk-and-kappo).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
compare(i) {
    if (this.comparison_variable == this.list[i]) {
      this.list.forEach((element, index) => {
        this.list[index] = this.comparison_variable;
      });
      return true;
    }
    else {
     this.list[i] = 'your default color';
     return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Its not working, I have also added my working code in above link kindly update in it

Comment: just missed 1 brace. sorry. i updated your code pls check again

Comment: if both value matches i want to make all boxes color same, how i can do this?

Comment: its already done above my code under the foreach loop. To test it try making the if condition to equal. like this `if (this.list[i] == this.list[i])`

Comment: your generation of the compared variable is hard to match with the generated colors of the six boxes

Comment: this is my updated code, I have compared the values and when user hit the correct option i want that the remaining boxes should have same color